# Configure symfony form label in doctrine config

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am currently on a project where i have a lot of entities with a lot of fields (clients with addresses, phones, age, firm number...), and i am doing it for a French client. So i code in English:

```
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;
}
```

And i have a config like this:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Client:
type: entity
table: null
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    firstName:
        type: string
        length: 255
        options:
            label: Prénom
```

So the options.label doesn't seem to work, i'm wondering where i could do these translations as it will concern a lot of fields, and as I am using Sonata admin i don't want to be obliged to put them in the `ClientAdmin` class:

```
/**
 * @param FormMapper $formMapper
 */
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('birthDate', 'birthday')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
 */
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('birthDate')
    ;
}
```

because i would have to translate at least twice (form, display...) so I would love it to handle one translation in all the app.

Any idea ? I looked into the Gedmo translatable extension, but it doesn't correspond to what I am looking for: i simply want to translate the labels of the form, the whole application will be in a unique language: french.

Symfony 2.6
Doctrine 2.2 to 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who don't know it, turned out that the automatic labels are already translation keys, you simply need to specify the translation_domain in your form, so i have now a `messages.fr.yml`:

```
First Name: Prénom
```

And it's enough! No need to generate / specify a translation label. Plus it is reusable in between forms with similar fields ! This works within our out of sonata admin's focus.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this. It will help you automate the translation process. http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle
You'll just have to use keys instead of real labels(although it's optional in your case), like this:

```
$formMapper
        ->add('firstName',null, array('label'=>'sonata.user.firstName')
```

Then you just run a command and it will extract all the keys in a nice web GUI, and you can translate them from there in whatever language you want.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but seems very uncomfortable to use, the main idea is to be able to NOT be obliged to specify the label  in the form because i will have to do this in several places. Isn't there a default label that I can translate ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. The bundle extracts everything from twig that has the trans or transchoice filter applied, labels from FormTypes and from controllers where you also call $translator->trans();...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 /**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Client',
        'label' => 'Prénom'
    ));
}
```

Comment: the goal is to put translations in another place so I precisely don't have to do this...

Comment: I use 'label' => 'my.translation.message' and it works perfectly

Comment: yes but in my case this will mean i have to put a `'label'=>'whatever'` both in my `configureFormFields` and `configureShowFields`, form all my entities, and even for additionnal forms. And that's what i want to avoid. I want doctrine to guess that my form `entity.field` will be translated by `form.entity.field`